# Close web resource after a long running asynchronous update

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online, dynamics-365

I make one call that retrieves multiple GUIDs using the WebAPI. I loop through each result and update records accordingly. This is all being done asynchronously. I do not want the user to wait for all the records to update and simply want to close the web resource. 
I use `window.close()` however, it is disrupting the asynchronous update calls that were previously initiated. How can I circumvent this? Here are the calls I am making:

```
window.opener.Xrm.WebApi.online.retrieveMultipleRecords("new_contract", "?$select=new_contractid&$filter=statecode eq 0 and statuscode eq 100000001&$top=5000")
    .then(function(results) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.entities.length; i++) {
            var new_contractid = results.entities[i]["new_contractid"];
            var processedGuid = new_contractid.replace(/[{}]/g, "");

            var entity = {};
            entity.new_run = new Date(y).toISOString();

            window.opener.Xrm.WebApi.online.updateRecord("new_contract", processedGuid, entity)
                .then(function success(result) {
                    var updatedEntityId = result.id;
                },
                function (error) {
                    Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
                });
        }
    }, function (error) {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog(error.message);
    });
```

I am thinking to use a plugin from the back end instead. I am not sure which approach to take, any input would be great!!

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately if you close the window, you close all its processes. You can either trigger a plugin, or outsource to Azure functions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend you “Custom Action” to achieve it, trigger & forget. Move all the logic in there.

> It seems we should be thinking of the custom actions as of the “functions”. Those functions can be defined as a mix of workflow steps and plugins – we can pass input parameters into the custom action and retrieve output parameters from the custom action. The reason we can call then “functions” is that, unlike with the workflow/plugins, we can, actually, call those functions from other places – we can call them from javascripts, we can call them from workflows, and we can call them from plugins.

[Read more](http://www.itaintboring.com/dynamics-crm/custom-actions/)

Answer (score 2):

You can't circumvent that, you are closing the window in which the code is executing.

You are probably better off using a plugin.